# Combining C# and C++ in VisualStudio solution

Tags: c#, c++, qt, boost, stl

I have quite complex project written in C++ and I'm trying to convert it into C# solution. I thought it would be easiest to left the core in C++, as VC++ class library.

Before I begin, I tried to write simple C++ class that way and use it in C# project. The first problem I get was STL (in core STL, Boost and QT are used): I can't pass C# List as std::list to C++ method.

Is there any easy way to use C++ code with STL, Boos and QT in C# or converting it to C# is easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion of C++ into C# is not possible. And there is also no reason to do it. There are some things you can do:

1) Rewrite the GUI in C#

2) Wrap C++ classes with C++/CLI and use them from C#

3) If your application is mostly Gui with not too complex logic behind it, you can use the parts of C++ code in C# in `unsafe` block.

What you definitely shouldn't do is transfer the c++ code into c# line by line.

Comment: By converting I mean copying it all and then changing all std/stl/boost/qt classes to similar C# classes and so on.

Comment: @Ari I understand, and that is something that you can't simply do. The 3 advices that I've given you is the best way you can "convert" c++ to c#

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible to rewrite the application layer by layer in C#? Sure, the C# containers can not be used as exact duplicates of the C++ container classes, and he can't transfer it line by line, but class by class (or tier by tier) should be possible.

Comment: @ArneMertz rewriting is not converting. Sure you can rewrite the whole code. But OP said, that the project is quite complex, that means he can't use/sell it before he completed rewriting it. That is why the best practice is to create new c# gui and wrap existing c++ code in c++/cli and then step by step rewrite the logic from c++ to c#

Comment: @VladL I think that's exactly what he meant by "converting" - rewriting the necessary classes without changing the grand design and architecture, reserving the individual classes' responsibilities. And since he wants to preserve the C++ core he's likely to convert only the gui and maybe one or two tiers beyond that, as he sees fit. The C++/CLI wrapper would be what he calls a "VC++ class library" I think.

Comment: @ArneMertz he said "I have quite complex project written in C++ and I'm trying to convert it into C# solution". There is nothing about particular rewriting. But still, the best way to run c++ and c# together is to use c++/cli. converting c++ guis ist schwachsinn, so 1) rewrite gui, 2) wrap c++ 3) move from c++ to c#